# How to convert shp to PostGIS dump?

Tags: postgis, shapefile, postgresql, esri-geodatabase, kmz

**Given a file my_file.shp** such those from Gadm [e.g. US administrative divisions](http://www.filefactory.com/file/5xkecujkx4sd/n/USA_adm_zip), where the coordinate reference system is latitude/longitude with WGS84 datum.

Input could actually be:

1. Shapefile,
2. ESRI personal geodatabase,
3. ESRI file geodatabase,
4. Google Earth .kmz,
5. R (SpatialPolygonsDataFrame)

**How to convert this input into a WGS84 PostGIS dump ?**

Comment: This ogr2ogr may help:
`ogr2ogr -overwrite -f "PostgreSQL" PG:"host=myhost user=myuser dbname=mydb password=mypass" my_file.shp` [ See: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/68417/ ]

Comment: shp2pgsql -I -s <SRID> <PATH/TO/SHAPEFILE> <SCHEMA>.<DBTABLE>

Comment: Iant, your answer is helpful. Please open an answer and explain a bit (SRID, Schema, DBtable).

Answer (score 3):

PostGIS comes with a shapefile loader called `shp2pgsql` which converts a shapefile into the SQL statements that are needed to load the data into PostGIS. You can find a detailed description of the command and the options needed on [this page](http://suite.opengeo.org/docs/dataadmin/pgGettingStarted/shp2pgsql.html).

But it boils down to something like:

```
shp2pgsql -I -s 4326 input.shp schema.table > output.sql
```

Comment: If i understand it well : `shp2pgsql -I -s <SRID> <PATH/TO/SHAPEFILE> <SCHEMA>.<DBTABLE> > <TARGET_NAME>.sql` or for a practical example `shp2pgsql -I -s 4326 input.shp layer_rivers > output.sql` . Could you confirm ?

Answer (score 2):

The simplest solution I can think of would be to import the shapefile into PostGIS using Shapefile to DBF loader (or if in another format write a scipt to upload using [ogr2ogr](http://www.gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html)).  Then once in PostGIS you can create the dump file.  If you use PgAdmin then both these operations are very easy as the shapefile loader is a plugin to PgAdmin and to dump, just right-click on your table and choose 'backup'.